# geoDjango - ImportError: cannot import name SpatialBackend

Tags: django, geodjango, importerror

Im trying to make an app with **geoDjango** but I'm actually having some problem to put it running.
When I excecute the "**python manage.py syncdb**" command, I have the following error:

```
File "/media/datos/Proyectos/CualBondi/git/cualbondi/myapp/models.py", line 10, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.sql import GeomField
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.sql.query import GeoQuery
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/sql/query.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import GeometryField
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.backend import SpatialBackend, gqn
ImportError: cannot import name SpatialBackend
```

I give you here some extra information:

- Django 1.3.1
- Python 2.6
- Ubuntu 10.04
- PostgreSQL 8.4.8

Do you have any idea?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps, SpatialBackend seems deprecated. Read the warning below.

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.gis.db.backend import SpatialBackend, gqn
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/contrib/gis/db/backend/__init__.py:5: UserWarning: The `django.contrib.gis.db.backend` module was refactored and renamed to `django.contrib.gis.db.backends` in 1.2.  All functionality of `SpatialBackend` has been moved to the `ops` attribute of the spatial database backend.  A `SpatialBackend` alias is provided here for backwards-compatibility, but will be removed in 1.3.
  warn('The `django.contrib.gis.db.backend` module was refactored and '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name gqn
```

I'm on django 1.3.0, there seems to work good, but only with that warning.